# fullcalendar event not stored in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am working on a project with full colander I am inserting updating and deleting events . on my localhost everything is working fine but on the server, only the insert method is not working

this is my insert page:
I am using PDO to connect to my data base

```html
<?php
session_start();
//insert.php

require_once 'app/helpers.php';
$link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");
$user = $_SESSION['u_id'];

$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$user'";
$sqlq= mysqli_query($link, $sql);
foreach ($sqlq as $email);
$x = $email['user_email'];

if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dror123_rge','dror123_dror','wed071211');
$connect->exec("set names utf8");
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO events 
 (title, user_uid, start_event,start_event_time, end_event,end_event_time ,user_email,status) 
 VALUES (:title,:user, :start,:stime, :end,:etime, :email,:status )
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
   ':user'  => $user,
   ':start' => $_POST['start'],
  ':stime' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end' => $_POST['end'],
':etime' => $_POST['end'],
 ':email' => $x,
':status' => $_POST['status']
  )
 );
```

this is my calendar page
you will find the script with the insert update and dleat at the end of the page

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?= require_once 'tpl/headertpl.php'; ?>

<link href="../assets/node_modules/sweetalert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../assets/node_modules/calendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-rounded error-messages" style="display: none; position: absolute; top:500px; left:500px; z-index: 50;" > <i class="ti-user"></i> This is an example top alert. You can edit what u wish.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">×</span> </button>
    </div>                <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">
                                <div id="calendar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
    <div class="modal none-border" id="my-event">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add Event</strong></h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-event waves-effect waves-light">Create event</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-event waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Add Category -->
    <div class="modal fade none-border" id="add-new-event">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add</strong> a category</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Category Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Enter name" type="text" name="category-name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Choose Category Color</label>
                                <select class="form-control form-white" data-placeholder="Choose a color..." name="category-color">
                                    <option value="success">Success</option>
                                    <option value="danger">Danger</option>
                                    <option value="info">Info</option>
                                    <option value="primary">Primary</option>
                                    <option value="warning">Warning</option>
                                    <option value="inverse">Inverse</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light save-category" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MODAL -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End PAge Content -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Right sidebar -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- .right-sidebar -->
    <div class="right-sidebar">
        <div class="slimscrollright">
            <div class="rpanel-title"> Service Panel <span><i class="ti-close right-side-toggle"></i></span> </div>
            <div class="r-panel-body">
                <ul id="themecolors" class="m-t-20">
                    <li><b>With Light sidebar</b></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-default" class="default-theme">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-green" class="green-theme">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-red" class="red-theme">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-blue" class="blue-theme working">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-purple" class="purple-theme">5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-megna" class="megna-theme">6</a></li>
                    <li class="d-block m-t-30"><b>With Dark sidebar</b></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-default-dark" class="default-dark-theme ">7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-green-dark" class="green-dark-theme">8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-red-dark" class="red-dark-theme">9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-blue-dark" class="blue-dark-theme">10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-purple-dark" class="purple-dark-theme">11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-skin="skin-megna-dark" class="megna-dark-theme ">12</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="m-t-20 chatonline">
                    <li><b>Chat option</b></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/1.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Varun Dhavan <small class="text-success">online</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/2.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Genelia Deshmukh <small class="text-warning">Away</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/3.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Ritesh Deshmukh <small class="text-danger">Busy</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/4.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Arijit Sinh <small class="text-muted">Offline</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/5.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Govinda Star <small class="text-success">online</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/6.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>John Abraham<small class="text-success">online</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/7.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Hritik Roshan<small class="text-success">online</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../assets/images/users/8.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> <span>Pwandeep rajan <small class="text-success">online</small></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End Right sidebar -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Container fluid  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Page wrapper  -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- footer -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<footer class="footer">
    © <?= date('Y') ?> Developed by Dror Shalit
</footer>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End footer -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Wrapper -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- All Jquery -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<script src="../assets/node_modules/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../assets/node_modules/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
<script src="dist/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Wave Effects -->
<script src="dist/js/waves.js"></script>
<!--Menu sidebar -->
<script src="dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
<!--stickey kit -->
<script src="../assets/node_modules/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/node_modules/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!--Custom JavaScript -->
<script src="dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
<!-- Calendar JavaScript -->

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var status = 1;
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: 'load.php',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            droppable: true,

            select: function (start, end, allDay)
            {
                var title = prompt("הכנס כותרת אירוע");
                if (title)
                {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "insert.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {title: title, start: start, end: end, status: status},
                        success: function ()
                        {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            editable: true,
            eventResize: function (event)
            {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var title = event.title;
                var id = event.id;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {title: title, start: start, end: end, id: id},
                    success: function () {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                    }
                })
            },

            eventDrop: function (event)
            {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var title = event.title;
                var id = event.id;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {title: title, start: start, end: end, id: id},
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                    }
                });
            },

            eventClick: function (event)
            {
                if (confirm("האם אתה בטחוח שאתה רוצה למחוק את האירוע?!"))
                {
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "delete.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function ()
                        {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                        }
                    })
                }
            },

        });
    });

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/node_modules/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/node_modules/sweetalert/jquery.sweet-alert.custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"i am using PDO to connect to my data base"* - Why are you using 2 different mysql apis?

Comment: I have just noticed it. this is was from an old version of the file. my bad... after I changed everything to PDO I still having the same problem... no data insert into the database in the server ...only in the localhost

Comment: Enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - and try one of these depending on the connection and query apis - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php -- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - and look at your developer console. If there are any errors, please update your question to contain what those were, if any. However, you shouldn't be connecting with one api then switching to another different one after. This may have adverse effects.

Comment: after a long time of testing i have manged to solve the problem. i deleted the table and created it again with an SQL statement in phpmyadmin. when i crated all the data base it was created in my local server... strangely only this table was unable to get data from the client side. thank you for your time and the wheeling to help!